# Blue screen 8 times after re install windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I had to reinstall my laptop using windows 7, and when it almost got to the desktop, there was a Blue screen and restart again to 8 times.
what actually happens on my laptop?
please solution

Comment: Why did you have to reinstall Windows 7?  Did you use factory recovery discs, or a recovery partition... or a full Windows 7 install disc?  Make and manufacture of the laptop?  Any idea of what the Blue Screen error code was?  If you could edit your question and supply more information, you'd be able to get more help.

Comment: My first operating system is windows 7 home premium, then i reinstalling by using windows 7 ultimate. so, here i just want to change from windows 7 home premium to windows 7 ultimate then the blue screen happens on my laptop

Comment: Did you purchase or download this copy of Windows 7 ultimate?  Have you been able to identify what the Blue screen error says when it pops up?  Why the upgrade/change to Ultimate?  Did the system run fine with Windows 7 Home Premium?  Again.. make and model laptop?

Comment: i cannot identify what the Blue screen error, and I think if I use ultimate edition i can get the better performance (it is only by my thoughts true or false i do not know)

Comment: Better performance doing what?  Better performance overall?  Again... where did you get the copy of Windows 7 Ultimate?  Did you buy a retail copy, or did you download it?  I'm pretty convinced already you downloaded it, since I don't know anyone who would spend $300 or so on a copy of Ultimate, just because they guessed it would improve performance.  Your issue could be with the copy of Ultimate you are trying to reinstall.  You want a solution?  Forget Ultimate.  Reinstall your original OS with the restore discs.

Comment: about ultimate series i downloaded it. is there any causes of it ?

Answer (score 2):

first let's see what messages are displayed on blue screen

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (0X0000000A)
This error most commonly appears in the event Blue Screen.
This error message is usually caused because there is a mismatch driver installed on your computer.
The cause:
- Drivers that clash or do not match
- Problems with the Video Card, this cover is to overclock the video card exceeds the limit or you've changed your video card and have not uninstalled the old video card drivers from the chipset is different
- Problems with the Audio Card, including configuration errors or bugs in the sound card driver

NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM or FAT_FILE_SYSTEM (0x00000024) or (0X00000023)
This error message is a little give at least where the damage is located, which is on a partition or filesystem but not in HD.
We can check by checking the SATA or PATA cable or tool can check the partition with chkdsk.

UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (0x0000007F)
If you get an error message like this, can be caused by:
- Excessive Hardware Overclock
- Components of a computer that is too hot
- BIOS is corrupt
- Memory and CPU is disabled

DATA_BUS_ERROR
This error message is caused because of the possibility that memory or the memory slot on the motherboard is damaged.

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
This error message is caused due to hardware malfunction, including main memory, video card, or memory in the processor (L2 Cache)

INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE
This error message is caused due to an error in the wrong hard drive jumper configuration, boot sector virus, the wrong IDE controller driver, or chipset driver error.

VIDEO_DRIVER_INIT_FAILURE
This error message is caused due to an error occurs on the video card driver installation is less than perfect, restart during the installation or can also occur because of errors in the installation
driver.

BAD_POOL_CALLER
Error message is caused because of this error can occur because of errors or incompatible drivers. Often occurs when installing XP from an upgrade, or rather of the new installation.

PEN_LIST_CORRUPT
This error message is caused due to damage to RAM

MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION
This error message is caused by a defective CPU, or an aggressively overclocked, and the power supply to power shortages or damaged.

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Any problems in SCSIPORT drivers that do not use folders as transfer buffer I / O.

DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_ERROR
This error is caused by an application tries to divide by zero (Divide BY ZERO). If you receive this error and do not know which application caused it, you can try checking the memory dump.

most likely your error occurs is BAD_POOL_CALLER
try to use Windows XP or change their laptop memory